# How to parse .daq file?

Tags: c#, c++, file-io

I have a file which contains logging of some data acquired by an embedded system.

Here is an example:

```
<HISDAQ-V0.1;COMPRESSION(TOKEN-ESC(4X, 0x10, 7, 13, 15))>
<DAQPRJ>
<ANALOG>
<CHANNEL id='0' name='TKist' unit='°C' />
<CHANNEL id='1' name='RGTist' unit='°C' /> .... 
</ANALOG>
<DIGITAL> 
<CHANNEL id='0' bit='0' name='HK1MischerAuf' /> .... 
</DIGITAL>
</DAQPRJ>
....
2012-04-10_00:00:00 pm 64.0 79.4 18.0 49.0 120.0 48.3 6683573.0 5.8 23.6 120.0 60.0 60@49.6 0.0 0.0 8 *8 5 8¡{13.4 -5.3 0 8à,8à6 8à 2 66838áU0.0 6.8 0 0 8 *8 7 8 3 18.08 3 66838¡U13.4 98À18À8 8Á{0.0 11.3 0 08À+8À9 8À2 18.08Áj13.4 9.8 0 08À+8À40 8Á{20.1 3.0 0 08À+8À1 8Á{6.7 3.8 0 0 8 *8 2 8¡{0.0 -68À18À3 8À3 78.18Ás14.3 08À-8À4 8Á4.5 0 8 ,8 5 8¡{20.1 6.8 0 08À+8À6 8Á{0.0 -08À18À7 8Á{13.4 9.1 0 08À+8À8 8À1 120.8Á`20.1 3.8 0 08À+8À9 8À0 18.0 49.0 8Ád6.7 5.3 0 0 8 *8 50 8¡{0.0 -3`8À+8À1 8Á6.8 0 8 ,8 2 8¡-1.5 08À-8À3 8À    7.9 188Ál6.7 3.0 0 0 8 *8 4 8¡{13.4 38À18À5 8À  8.0 188Ál0.0 4.5 0 0 8 *8 6 8¡{13.4 5.3 0 08À+8À7 8À    7.9 188Ál20.1 -3.0 0 8à,8à8 8á2.3 0......á
--- EOF---
```

(EOF is from me and it's not really inside the file!)

I've searched the web but did not find anything about that file format.

I see that first there is a description of the analog and digital channels (like a column header) and then follows the data. But I can not figure out the separators.

The best thing would be to have a piece of C++/C# code which can handle that data-file.

Anyone that can help?

Comment: It might be a loose variant of XML or more broadly [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML). I'm not sure it really conforms to the XML spec.

Comment: Not XML, since `;` may not appear in a tag name.

Comment: If its a Data Acquisition Toolbox 2.6 DAQ file, maybe this will help http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-1NBX1T/index.html?product=DA&solution=1-1NBX1T Basically if you have mathlab, you can inspect the daqread function to see how the file is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like XML, so I'd be tempted to look into the .NET XML parsing functions [Here: might be a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). I deal witha  lot of XML these days, and it's really easy to use in C#.

As for the meaning behind the syntax (as in what each attribute/element means and how to use it in your logic), only you or an expert will know. you might have to sit with the client/customer or a fellow engineer to figure that one out.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**:

To read the final section, you could read the entire file as a string, then create a substring of it - starting on the location of the last > and reading until the EOF marker. That way, you have your "data" in a string, and you can manipulate/parse it further in whatever manner you need to.

The null character that terminates a string is, usually, "\0" in C#

Comment: yes, that was my first thought as well, but after the "definition" of the "columns" the data has no surrounding "<" and ">", its only numbers with some sort of special signs. I can See "DLE ACK DC2 NUL BEL VT" and some "8À+" and "8À-"

Comment: As other's have said, it looks like it's based off of XML. Which means, aside from some of the XML-illegal characters, you should be able to parse most of it using XML. The final line might be a problem, but (as I've said in my answer), you might have to sit with an engineer/customer who has used the embedded system you are looking at to be able to figure out what the data means. Once you've done that, parsing the rest of it should be pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with .daq files - but this approach might help, I used it with 'loose' or fragmented XML files, miss-formatted ones etc.

I think you have a `'header' + XML + data`.

Parse the header out first - it seems just like one `<>` - or maybe always on the line as well.

With the next opening `<` (I'm guessing the format but looks like that) you start the XML.

Search for the `'end >'` - you can use LastIndexOf - should do.

And that's your XML, load it with LINQ to XML e.g. - and then the `rest` is really the data.

hope this helps